# Given first order partial derivatives exist, is it always possible that mixed partial exist?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

If two-variable function $\ f(x,y)$
is partialy differentiable respect to both variables ;
if both
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $
and
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} $
exist,
is it always true the second mixed partial
$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} $
exist?

If it's not the general case, what could be the weakest condition that fit?

Well using my intuition
$\ f_x$ and $\ f_y$ being continuous is
the best I could imagine,
but I guess that's not all?
Please enlighten me.

I'm currently learning calculus by Stewart calculus ed.8

If exact answer requires rigorous understanding of math concepts
Which books/texts do I need to look for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $$f(x,y)=e^{1/(x^2+y^2)} x y, \qquad f(0,0)=0$$ Away from $(0,0)$ it is smooth, but at $(0,0)$ only the partial derivatives in directions $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ exist, not in the direction $(1,1)$. The $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}$ second derivative doesn't exist neither.

Another example would be

$$g(x,y)=xy\sin(\frac1{x^2+y^2})$$
It is smooth away from $(0,0)$.

$g(x,y)=O(x^2+y^2)$ so the derivatives in every directions exist and vanish at $(0,0)$, but $(\partial_x g)(0,y)=y\sin(1/y^2)$ which is not differentiable at $y=0$ so that $(\partial_y (\partial_x g))(0,0)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: That's appreciatable counterexample! Now I can see.